# how to automate a button html

Tags: php, html, c++, sql, arduino

So I have written this HTML code to create a webpage and after reading an RFID tag. The page then creates a button on the webpage that must be clicked in order to upload the data to the sql database.

How do I make this automatic so when the tag is read it will automatically upload the tag data without asking the user to click the upload button?

I am trying to use the `<meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”5" />`function but am unsure where to put it in my code

An help please? how do I remove the 'upload code' button to automate the process and refresh the page each time a tag is read

```
void loop() {

// Check if a client has connected
client = server.available();
if (!client) {
  return;
}

// Wait until the user sends some data
Serial.println("New User");
while (!client.available()) {
  delay(1);
}

//Wait for serial data to be available i.e. because a tag has been scanned
if(Serial.available()) { //Read the serial port and store the data in char array
    Serial.println("Data available");
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++) {
        val = Serial.read();
        valArray[i] = val;
        yield();
        //delay(10)
    }

    Serial.print(valArray);

    // write to client  
    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    client.println("<html>");
    client.println("<head>");
    client.println("<title>ESP8266 Demo</title>");
    client.println("</head>");
    client.println("<body>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/\">Refresh Status</a>");
    client.println("</br></br>");        
    String strLink1 =  "<a href='http://xxxxxxxx.com/track.php?RFID=";
    String strLink2 = "'>Upload Tag ID</a>";
    String strLink = strLink1 + valArray + strLink2;
    client.println(strLink);
    client.println("</br></br>");
    client.print("RFID Tag No = ");
    client.print(valArray);
    client.println("</br>");
    client.println("</body>");
    client.println("</html>");




}

//client.stop();
delay(100);
```

}

Comment: Why don't you call the URL directly from your script instead?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. this is my script. All I have is another php script, stored on my web server, called track which connects to the sql db and post the result to it

Comment: This script (in whichever language it may be) serves a HTML page, which is probably read by a web browser, which you then want to call your `track.php` script. So you have script 1 -> browser -> script 2. You could probably call script 2 directly from script 1 without the need for a browser in the middle. But you would need to tell us which language / environment you're using.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes the first script is in Arduino C and the second HTML script is is  embedded within the main Arduino program. when the (http://xxxxxxxx.com/track.php?RFID=) is run, it activates the php script

Comment: Might want to adjust your tags to get views from people that are more experienced in this area.  This looks like it has little to do with `SQL` and potentially more to do with `PHP` and `C` or `C++`?

Comment: If Arduino C enables you to make a HTTP request, then have your script directly make a request for the `track.php` URL. No need to involve a browser if all you want to do is automatically call that URL (unless we don't have the full picture, which is more than possible).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. How would I call the URL automatically? I tried  to use the HTML POST function but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting this below the button:

```
<script>document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].click();</script>
```

or some equivalent that is ran when needed, I'm not very clear on the when of it.